# How to map JPA Entity to SQL View in Play Framework 1

Tags: jpa, orm, playframework, playframework-1.x, sql-view

How can I map JPA Entity to SQL View in play framework 1? I chose PostgreSQL for its materialized view, but how to query these views elegantly. I don't want to use native query everywhere which using SQL Views. Is there any way to query them in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `@Table` annotation to map your entity class to a view in postgreSQL.
E.g. when you have a view in PostgreSQL which is named `CustomerView` define you entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerView")
public class Customer extends Model {

}
```

Comment: A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): No identifier specified for entity: models.DepartmentQuestionInfo

Comment: You have to provide an identifier... Play provides a base class which provides and id for you entity classes. Just extend your class from `play.db.jpa.Model`. (I also updated my answer).

Comment: You should read the play documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/jpa#anamesupportTheplay.db.jpa.Modelsupportclassa